# Is there a better term for 'low-level?'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms, terminology

In computer programming, *low-level* means something used as a base upon which to build more complex mechanisms.  To the untrained ear, I think the term might imply inferiority, which is simply not the case.  I'm worried that people will think it is synonymous with *basic,* which is just plain wrong!  (Indeed, low-level programming can be extremely complex.)

Is there a better term I could use?  It should, in a nutshell, describe something that is necessary to form more complex things.  A slightly technical tinge to the word is preferable, but not strictly necessary.

Comment: How about *neck deep*?

Comment: @Jim I've only ever heard that used as a hyperbole, e.g. "We're neck deep in paperwork."  I'm not so sure it would work here.

Comment: Yeah, I felt kind of iffy on it (hence the comment, rather than an answer). Seemed somewhat appropriate, though, as you would be neck-deep in the inner workings of a computer. It would convey to non-computer people that there is a lot of work and complexity.

Comment: If you're worried about what untrained ears will hear, call it Genius-Level Programming. These are people who don't even understand the concept, let alone the actual work involved.

Comment: Can you clarify what are you exactly talking about (you might get better answers)? Low-level is inherently relative - you might be talking about so many things; see some issues here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- [Foundational](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/foundational) (fundamental or underlying)
- Machine-level (or, informally, "[bare-metal programming](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/B/bare_metal_programming.html) ... is considered to be a low-level method of programming that is specific to the hardware used in the computer system  and is often used for optimizing software and applications for an individual computer")
- System internals
- System-level
- [Underpinnings](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/underpinning) (support or foundation)

Comment: Personally, I think of "foundational" as having a connotation of being basic, but +1 for the other suggestions.

Comment: "foundational" would have been my suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

A few I can think of:

- "Fundamental"
- "Core"
- "Kernel"

Comment: +1 for *core.*  *Kernel* might be too confusing for a non-technical audience, and *fundamental* might also have negative connotations (though the dictionary definition fits the bill perfectly).

Comment: I find that "fundamental" has a positive connotation actually, something like "basic and essential".

Comment: You're probably right, actually.

Answer (score 3):

I think *foundational* and *core* are quite good options. I'd just add to the list the word ***infrastructural***. It may have more of the "technical tinge" you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

*Close-to-the-metal* gives a descriptive representation of what you’re talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I like *building block* here.  If something is at the lowest level it is the building block that everything else rests.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *bedrock*.

> [**bedrock**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Specious?s=t): *Americanism:* basic; fundamental: [**bedrock programming**](http://www.businessinsider.com/bedrock-programming-2012-9).

Answer (score 0):

Primitive or Proto too can be used if you are being pessimistic about your "low-level"

Comment: These would benefit from some examples and appropriate definitions for each suggested word.